# How to have a loop to generate ORDER BY statements from a string that is converted to an array

Tags: postgresql

I have a string like "Joe Bob Alex" and I matched it with `%Bob%`and I want to split that into an array and generate order by statements. For example I would want the result to be

```
name1 ASC,
name2 ASC,
name3 ASC,
```

There may be some other way to do it but I've been trying to put a loop in the ORDER BY clause that splits the array and generates those lines but I just can't get it to work.

This I'm working with Postgres Sql (the specific package is "node-postgres-named". An example I've tried (which could be way off, I'm not the best with Sql) is:

```
(some_boolean IS TRUE) DESC NULLS LAST,
CASE WHEN something ilike :search then something end ASC,
DO $$DECLARE name record;
BEGIN
    FOR name IN string_to_array(names, ' ') LOOP
      name ASC,
    END LOOP; 
END$$;
dist ASC
```

Comment: How do you get from `'Joe Bob Alex'` to `e'name1 ASC,\nname2 ASC,\nname3 ASC,'`? I don't get the logic.

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL query please? It's not quite clear what this is. It seems you want to generate the `ORDER BY` clause of an ordinary `SELECT` statement, but then you begin mixing this with procedural pl/pgsql code that doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi  string_to_array('Joe Bob Alex').

I'm working with some crappy inline sql. I have to generate an ORDER BY statement as a string and yeah the procedural stuff probably doesn't work, that's why I'm looking for help. I was just showing a poor attempt of mine I guess. I just need to iterate over the elements of the array and generate some CASE statements for each of the elements of the array.

Comment: What is your actual goal? What does the table look like, what data is in there (just a short example), and what query result do you expect? Please [edit] your question to post the full query statement that you want to generate. Also what do you mean by "*some crappy inline sql*"? Please post the javascript code that is using the sql string.